# car and quote in Lisp

Tags: lisp, quote

I am currently studying about Lisp but I still don't get quote.

Why use quote in Lisp?

And I got a problem here which is hard to understand to me.

```
(car (car '((a b) c d)))
```

The above gives `A`.

But I don't know why the result is `A` because there is no quote first car after.

Comment: What result did you first expect?

Answer (score 4):

`quote` is an operator; its meaning only kicks in when it is the head of a Lisp expression which is evaluated. The syntax `'X` stands for `(quote X)`: the Lisp reader translates a prefix apostrophe, followed by any syntactic unit X denoting one object, into the syntax `(quote X)`. The `quote` expression, when evaluated, returns the syntax `X` *itself* as the value, rather than the value of the syntax. For instance `(quote (+ 1 2))` returns the three element list `(+ 1 2)`, rather than the value of the expression `(+ 1 2)` which is `3`.  `quote` effectively **reflects** a piece of the program's list-based syntax back into the running program as a value.

In the expression:

```
(car (car '((a b) c d)))
```

we simply have a nested function application to a value:

```
(car (car value))
```

This value is the result of a `quote` expression, and so the value is the object `((a b) c d)`. This object started out as a piece of syntax wrapped inside quote, but is now a run-time value being passed to the `car` function. The inner `car` produces the first element of the list, returning `(a b)`. This `(a b)` value is passed to the outer `car`, which retrieves the `a`.

Lisp provides `quote` because it is a homoiconic language. The principal data structures manipulated in that language have a printed notation, and that printed notation is used to write programs also. Thus programs are understood to be made out of a data structure.  In this kind of language, suppose you want to be able to use any data structure as a literal. Of course, that creates confusion because the data uses the same notation as the code, and some data structures look like valid syntax. You need an operator which you can wrap around a piece of syntax to say, "this is literal data; do not evaluate this as an expression, but just the data that it looks like".

This is exactly the same like when we use English to talk *about* English. We have to use quotes—at least when we write this talk down. A sentence like:

> A penny saved is a penny earned is a good old proverb.

is badly written. Of course we understand what it means because our brains are good at dealing with ambiguity and mistakes, but it appears to be saying that a penny is a proverb. We need quotes:

> "A penny saved is a penny earned" is a good old proverb.

See? The quote says that this sentence is not a relative clause of my sentence; it's text that my sentence is talking about (which happens to be in the same language that I'm using to talk about it). This is why the Lisp operator is called `quote`: it's related to this type of quoting.

Comment: The only quibble I have with this is that Common Lisp evaluation and semantics are defined on "forms", not on "syntax", the difference being is that "syntax" is what you have before the reader is done and "forms" is what you have when the reader has finished.

Comment: @Vatine What you have before the reader is "character syntax" (also called "read syntax"). It produces expressions. Forms are expressions which are intended to be evaluated. In `(let ((a b)))`, `(a b)` is read syntax (traditionally, "S-expression") which reads to an expression. That expression isn't a form.  The `b` part, however, is.

Comment: @Vatine *ANSI CL 3.1.2.1.2.1 Special Forms* begins: "A special form is a form with special syntax, special evaluation rules, or both ...".  See? A form has syntax.

Answer (score 3):

## Why use quote

Think of the quote as an indication that it's data and not to be thought of as code:

```
(cons 1 2)  ; ==> (1 . 2)    (a cons with car as 1 and cdr as 2)
'(cons 1 2) ; ==> (cons 1 2) (a list with the symbol cons and the numbers 1 and 2)
```

You see in the first that is not quoted it's executed and the result is the result of the `cons` function. In the second you could say `quote` is executed and it evaluates soley to it's argument. Note that `'x` is just an abbrevation for `(quote x)` and both thus evaluate to `x` while without quote it would evaluate to the value bound to the variable `x`.

## Nested functions

When you nest functions like `(car (car '((a b) c d))))` you'll se why you need to quote since all arguments in functions are evaluated. Thus before the outer `car` can be applied it needs to evaluate it's argument `(car '((a b) c d)))` and before the inner car can do it's job it needs to evaluate it's argument `'((a b) c d))`. We know that `'((a b) c d))` becomes `((a b) c d))` and `car` of this is `(a b)`. The outer car then works on `(a b)` and thus `a` is the result. If you would have put the quote like this `(car '(car ((a b) c d))))` then the innser car is just a symbol in the data structure and not a function. `car` evaluates its argument to be `(car ((a b) c d)))` and `car` of that is the symbol `car`.

```
'((a b) c d))             ; ==> ((a b) c d))
(car '((a b) c d))        ; ==> (a b)
(car (car '((a b) c d)))  ; ==> a

'(car ((a b) c d))        ; ==> (car ((a b) c d))
(car '(car ((a b) c d)))  ; ==> car
```

Also know that if you put quotes inside quoted data, like `''x` only the outer quote is taken off and the rest is data. The result is `(quote x)` or `'x` depending on the display settings but since it's already data `quote` here is just a symbol. `(car ''x) ; ==> quote (symbol)`